# How to run parallel commands to upload directory in gcp in shell script

Tags: shell, powershell

How to run parallel commands to upload directory in gcp in a shell script

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to run parallel commands in Powershell is using Jobs.
A quick search found this blog post:
https://4sysops.com/archives/powershell-background-job-basics/
As for the commands you want to run in parallel, I didn't get enough information from the question you asked. If you want to elaborate I might be able to try and help.